# How to run Corb job using Gradle

Tags: gradle, marklogic, marklogic-corb

I have uri module and process module xqy file setup and provided dependencies, configurations, plugins etc in build.gradle file. I want to know How to run the file using Gradle.

Answer (score 2):

You can find instructions at: https://github.com/marklogic-community/ml-gradle/wiki/Corb-and-Gradle